React vite-plugin-federation not working inside components (only in localhost)
I'm trying to use federated components. If I use them inside my main.tsx, they work perfectly but if I try to use them inside a component, the app shows an empty screen and leaves no console errors whatsoever. The extra ingredient is that this happens only in dev mode, localhost
main.tsx v1
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import EmployeesDataDisplay from 'shared/EmployeesDataDisplay';

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement).render(
  <>
    <EmployeesDataDisplay employeeId={1}>PEPE</EmployeesDataDisplay>
  </>
)

enter image description here
main.tsx v2
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import { TestRemote } from './TestRemote';

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement).render(
  <>
    <TestRemote />
  </>
)

TestRemote.tsx
import EmployeesDataDisplay from 'shared/EmployeesDataDisplay';

export const TestRemote = () => {

  return (
    <>
      <EmployeesDataDisplay employeeId={1}>PEPE</EmployeesDataDisplay>        
    </>
  )
}

enter image description here
If remove the federated component from TestRemote.tsx and put a random text, it works as well.

Seems to be a browser issue. It doesn't work with Chrome and chromium based browsers but seems to work fine with opera.
